# Onsenui app add custom function on navigator click

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I develop a Onsenui app on Monaca and I'd like to add a custom function on my `on-right-button-click event` :

```
<ons-navigator 
  title="MyTitlte"
  right-button-icon="fa fa-lg fa-refresh"
  on-right-button-click="refresh()"
  page="pages/msg.html">
</ons-navigator>
```

my `refresh()` function is defined in my controller

```
moduleApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) { 

   // Refresh items
   $scope.refresh = function () {
    ....
   };
}]);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set **"MyController"** on the navigator or above the navigator.

```
<ons-navigator
  ng-controller="MyController" 
  title="MyTitlte"
  right-button-icon="fa fa-lg fa-refresh"
  on-right-button-click="refresh()"
  page="pages/msg.html">
</ons-navigator>
```